# Issue in POST request for Spring Boot with Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I have a simple rest service for post, while trying to print the content of the json message which I posted from postman, the value printed is "null", I think @RequestBody is always receiving null value.

The data class is

> data class User(val id:String?, val name:String?)

The controller class is

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping
class DemoController{
    @PostMapping ("/test")
    public fun test(@RequestBody user:User){
        print(user.id);
        println(user.name);
    }
}
```

The result prints null always,
I am using spring Boot version 2.4.0-SNAPSHOT ( same issue even with 2.3.3)
Kotlin version 1.4.0.

Comment: Can you post your json content please ? Here, user cannot be null, so it looks like it received a user without any name nor id (Ex: `{}`).

Comment: This is my json  {
  "body": {
      "id":"12345",
    "name": "Rizan"
  }
}

Comment: Since the requestBody is User object, your request should be sent as `{ "id":"12345", "name": "Rizan" }` instead

Comment: And try always to Debug your code without trying to make a print or printing function, it will help you more to follow the execution of your application